# EF Fault when retrieving data: wrong table name in SQL

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datacontext

I have a simple `edmx` with 2 tables. The tables are related by a single `Navigation Property`. (1 to many).

When I run my code I get an **Exception: "Invalid Object Name dbo.Enquiries"**

There is no `dbo.Enquiries` in the database (it is actually called `dbo.Enquiry`), so the error itself is self explanatory. **But where is it finding that Name, and how do I fix it?**

*Edited to show code as requested.*

```
 var foo = (from  d in context.Dealerships
            join e in context.Enquiry
                on d.Id equals e.DealershipId
            where (d.ParentBusinessId == id)
            select d).AsEnumerable();
```

Here is the sql that is generated.

```
  foo   {SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[BusinessName] AS [BusinessName]
FROM  [dbo].[Dealerships] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Enquiries] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Id] = 
[Extent2].[DealershipId]
WHERE [Extent1].[ParentBusinessId] = @p__linq__0}
```

But for the life of me I can't see where / how it is deciding to change the name Enquiry to Enquiries on the inner join.

Comment: when you run "which" code ?

Comment: I didnt see any point in showing the code as all it does is to try and pull in from teh 2 tables. If I then investigate in debugger then the data from the primary table is there, but not that of the secondary. The SQL in the debugger shows it is looking for the wrong table, so it is an issue with one of the designers I think, but I will edit to show the code.

Answer (score 5):

Found the Answer. the Pluralise Is only on Model Generation. I had to explicitly tell my DbContext not to Pluralise the names (I dare not start to rename this database, so Im stuck with the weird convention that was used.)

```
  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
  }
```

Comment: +1 but you may find that when working with an existing db you benefit from using configuration to specify table names explicitly.  For example, you can use class names that fit in with your C# coding standards even if your table names don't.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the table from the edmx and after update the model.

Comment: Didnt make any difference Im afraid

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are employing Model based development. If this is the case, then you seem to make some changes in the model, but did not reflect them to database.

Use the option generate database from model, and it will synchronize the database with the model.

Comment: No, the database already existed, I generated the models from the existing database.

Comment: can you try "Update Model from database" again?

Comment: Makes no difference, sorry.

Comment: there is an option in the edmx stating whether to use plural or singular database names / entity names; most probably this is somehow not working properly. While you are updating your model from database, uncheck pluralize or singularize generated object names.

Comment: I have done that, deleted my edmx and recreated it. Keeping the tick boxes unchecked and it still happens. However I suspect that this is along the right lines of finding the solution.

Comment: you may just open the EDMX file with an xml editor, and try to fix this manually.

Comment: nothing in the edmx file called Enquiries, and I forced plurality to be off.

Comment: in the edmx file there are three sections, CSDL, MSL and SSDL representing entities, mapping and database. search for "<EntityContainer Name" keyword and check the table names...

Comment: that was still ok. EF was forcing the sql generation to be pluralised elsewhere. I found some code to switch it off in my context. (Detailed in anotehr post on this thread, but as I posted it I can't mark it as asnwered. Thanks for trying to help though :)

Answer (score 0):

Try closing the Graphical view to EF model.
The right click edit and open in XML editor.
The mapping to table should be there and you can correct it.
OR
If you have chnaged the mode since import/Update, You could Completely delete the model and Import the Model again.
Code that accessed the model should be still Ok.

Comment: the mapping appears to be correct there, searching the whole file for enquiries shows no results.
I have deleted te entire model, restarted teh PC, recreated it and it is still there.

Debugger on my code shows that context.Enquiry is calling the table Enquiries, so it is somethign fundamental that is going on, especially as I have pluralising turned off..

Comment: Fixed the issue by adding the code block elsewhere in this thread. I just can't mark as answered for 2 days.

Comment: thanks for feedback, I have never needed modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove  but will keep in mind.  +1 for answer.